# ¿Como paginar una carta desde el controller en laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, controller

[image: este es el controller de mi view]

**Route::get('/shop', [CartController::class, 'shop'])->name('shop');** tengo ademas esta ruta en web.php por la cual envio mi function al view.. Tengo 24 products cargados en la base de datos y quisiera podes mostrar de a 10 por pagina, trate de usar paginate en la query **$products = Product::paginate;(10)** pero me marcaba error..
En el viewshop.blade.php lo llamo con un foreach: 
 `@foreach($products as $pro) all the code @endforeach` 
 El tema es que funciona que me muestre, nada mas que no lo puedo paginar de a 10 o de a 12 por ejemplo... ayuda

Comment: Ayudaría mucho si indicas que error generaba el usar el método paginate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando extraes los datos tienes que hacer esto:

```
//en el controlador
$products=Product::paginate(10);

//en la vista
$producs->links();
```

si tienes una tabla por ejemplo seria asi

```
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>
    </th
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <thbody>
    @foreach($products as $prod)
    <tr>
    <td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
    </table
    $products->links();
```